# Why are parameters not sent to a function in setInterval() all the time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, setinterval

I have a page that automatically refreshes content via Ajax. I want this to be subtle so I do not want to display my loading gif during automatic page refreshed. So I did something like this with my getPosts function (unnecessary code cut out for succinctness)

```
function getPosts(image) 
            {
                //loading icon while getPosts
                if (image)
                {
                    $("#postcontainer").bind("ajaxStart", function(){
                        $(this).html("<center><img src='ajax-loader.gif' /></center>");
                });
                } //... ajax call, etc. don't worry about syntax errors, they aren't in real code
```

I know the center tag is deprecated, just a shameless shortcut.
And then I will set the interval like `setInterval(function() { getPosts(false); }, 10000);`
Therefore my automated calls will not trigger the image to display
All my manual refreshes will then call it like this `getPosts(true);`

You can (probably) see the bug in action at [my personal site](http://www.ethoma.com/testhome.php)

The problem is, the setInterval function seems to use the image bool from the latest function call. So it does not display the image at first during automated calls, but after I click a manual refresh, it starts showing the image during each call.

How can I combat this?

Thanks for anyone who views/posts this topic! I hope this question becomes a good reference to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that once you've bound your "ajaxStart" handler to the container it will execute on every ajax call for that container. That is, the first time you call it with `getPosts(true)` it will create the binding. The next time you call it with `getPosts(false)` it doesn't go down that `if` path but the binding still exists so when you do your ajax call the handler still executes - and the handler doesn't doesn't have any conditional logic. (Actually, I believe you'll end up with multiple bindings on the "ajaxStart" event, one created every time you call `getPosts(true)`, but they're probably not noticable since they all just do the same thing overwriting the same html.)

Why not do something like this:

```
function getPosts(image) {
  if (image) {
    $("#postcontainer").html("<center><img src='ajax-loader.gif' /></center>");
  }

  // Actual ajax call here
}

setInterval(function() { getPosts(false); }, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because after the first manual refresh you have attached a event handler "ajaxstart" which is to show the image when a ajax call starts. Now this event handler is there even in case you call the function with image = false. It will get triggered on all ajax calls.

What you need to do is something like:

```
 $("#postcontainer").bind("ajaxStart", function(){
                        $(this).html("<center><img src='ajax-loader.gif' /></center>")
          //Remove event handler
          $(this).unbind("ajaxStart");
});
```